# Proof of Rudin Theorem 1.20 (b)

Tags: real-analysis

This is different to the linked question as the answers to that question do not address the actual process of finding m1 and m2.

The theorem states:

> (a) If x ∈ R, y ∈ R and x >0, then there exist a positive integer n such that nx >y.
>
> (b) If x ∈ R, y ∈ R, and x < y, then there exists a p ∈ Q such that x < p < y.

I understand part (a) of the theorem. Proof of part (b) opens as follows:

> Since *x* < *y* , we have *y - x* > 0 and (a) furnishes a positive integer *n* such that
> *n(y - x)* > 1.

This part I understand. But I'm unsure how this next part is done:

> Apply (*a*) again, to obtain positive integers *m1* and *m2* such that *m1* > *nx*, *m2* > -*nx*. Then -*m2* < nx < *m1*

How are the integers m1 and m2 obtained? I know that it involves the same process used in part a, I just can't figure out the steps.

Comment: Are we all supposed to know what is the statement of that theorem?

Comment: I'll add it now

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Thanks for marking it as a duplicate... The answer you linked skips the part that I'm asking for clarification on.

Comment: And sorry @MichaelRozenberg but I don't know how to use it. Beginner here.

Comment: For every real number $r$, you can find an integer $n_r$ such that $n_r>r$.
$nx$ is a real number, so there exists an integer $m_1$ such that $m_1>nx$.
$-nx$ is a real number, so there exists an integer $m_2$ such that $m_2>-nx$.
Multpily the last inequality by $-1$.
Combine the two inequalities, to get $-m_2<nx<m_1$.

Comment: Thanks @uniquesolution, that makes more sense now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - Regarding your question: No, not all of us. However, those of us who do not, should not rush to close the question down. No need to be mean to new users.

Comment: @uniquesolution I closed the question for one and only one reason: because it is a duplicate.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have explained above how it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @rory_c *Now* it is a duplicate. The *question* that I've put a link to contains an answer to your question.